# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application VScode

Tags: java, json, javafx, vscode, java-14

tengo problema al intentar ejecutar un proyecto javaFX, he buscado en internet pero todo lo que encuentro ya lo tengo realizado pero aun asi sigo teniendo el:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

este es mi archivo `launch.json`:

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - HellowFX",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-HelloFX<interfazRegresion_cd7940a2>",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "HelloFX",
            "projectName": "interfazRegresion_cd7940a2",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path C:\\Users\\David Mesa\\Desktop\\intro\\java\\interfaz regresion\\interfazRegresion\\lib\\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\\lib\\ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics"
        }
    ]
}
```

ya tengo importadas las librerias de java SDK, mi java home esta correcto. Ya se que este problema se ha publicado antes, pero los he revisado, y no encuentro solucion, igual los tutoriales, ya intale y desinstale el java y lo reconfigure en VScode pero sigue igual.

Comment: que versión de Java usas?

Comment: uso la version java 14

Comment: usas algún plugin de vscode para correrlo?

Comment: no, solo tengo el javaExtensionsPack, pero para el javaFX no uso nada, solo importo las libreias descargadas al proyecto.

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode